# Separating variables in some string

Tags: java

How do I separate  variables (or negated variables)  in some string with some separator like  `^`

Example:

```
String vars= "ABC'DE'F";
```

should looks like this:

```
"A^B^C'^D^E'^F"
```

Comment: You mean to say each character is a variable and you want to add a `^` after that ?

Comment: Did you miss out on a ^ before A also? Otherwise please explain the condition of appending ^

Comment: @shg: yes every character is a variable

Comment: @Afrin, they are atom-separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direct string replacement, use:

```
vars.replaceAll("(?!^)\\w", "^$0")
```

Output:

```
A^B^C'^D^E'^F
```

Comment: you have a leading `^` there... You could remove it by adding a positive look-behind of an arbitrary character.

Comment: Nice one. Regex updated.

Answer (score 4):

To separate the atoms you could do

```
String vars= "ABC'DE'F";

String[] atoms = vars.split("(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])");

// atoms = [A, B, C', D, E', F]
```

To insert `^` directly, you could do

```
vars = vars.replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])", "^");

// vars = A^B^C'^D^E'^F
```

Comment: now just run a stringbuilder thru the atoms set, add a ^ and you're good ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void replace() {
    String str = "ABC'DE'F";
    String pattern = "('?\\w)";

    str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "^$1");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

prints:

```
^A^B^C^'D^E^'F
```